# Is it possible to show by command how many voice channels my Discord bot is currently connected to?

Tags: discord, client, discord.py

I would like to display via command how many voice channels my bot is currently in, is this possible? Maybe also with extra things like the server ID/channel ID. This is not needed though, just the command and the amount would be good.
I already found a method for `js` but not for Discord.py.

Comment: Check for client.guild, and who is on voice channel, and if id user == bot count +=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Bot.voice_clients` attribute

```py
voice_states = bot.voice_clients # or client, however you named your instance

await ctx.send(f'I am currently in {len(voice_states)} voice channels')
```